# Python "ImportError: No module named mysql.connector" error

Tags: python, mysql, pip

This issue has been covered elsewhere but the solutions provided are not working for me.

I have python 3.7 installed on my Debian 10 system. Used below to install mysql-connector:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

On executing python script with below:

```
import mysql.connector
```

Seeing the below error:

```
"ImportError: No module named mysql.connector"
```

I have tried the pip3 search function to find the correct package name but this appears to no longer be supported.

Looking at what has worked for others I have attempted the below:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf
sudo python3 -m pip install mysql-connector-python
```

After which the error still persists.

Also tried below which returns no installation candidate:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-mysql.connector
```

Can anybody see the problem here?

---

Edit: Tried below as per suggestion in comments:

1. Fetched module mysql_connector_python-8.0.26-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
2. Executed:

   python3 -m pip install mysql_connector_python-8.0.26-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

Response:

```
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python==8.0.26 from file:///home/XXXX/Desktop/mysql_connector_python-8.0.26-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl in /home/XXXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (8.0.26)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.0.0 in /home/XXXX/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mysql-connector-python==8.0.26) (3.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from protobuf>=3.0.0->mysql-connector-python==8.0.26) (1.12.0)
```

Same error on executing python script.

Comment: Google → pypi → Search to decide module name "mysql.connector" → https://pypi.org/search/?q=mysql.connector . ...... Debian package names are python-mysql.connector, python3-mysql.connector : Please use `apt-cache search [name]` .... or https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=mysql.connector ... but nothing for Debian 10 .

Comment: Thanks. Very strange, I installed module  mysql_connector_python-8.0.26-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl and getting error suggesting it is already installed -> "Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python==8.0.26 from file..."